# How can I connect my "cfbuilder" to my server?

Tags: windows, coldfusion, amazon-rds

I'm trying to set up a connection to a **Cold Fusion 11** server with **cfbuilder 3**.

I'm working remotly with an **rds** set up.

When I start to start the server from the connection, I get this error:

> Cannot start or stop myserver. Remote server settings required to start and stop server have not been provided.

I really want to connect it for having access to a debugger.

Is there any suggestion for my problem?

Comment: Can you re-check that you provided the correct RDS user name and password?

Answer (score 0):

You need need to be running the Admin server instance in the remote ColdFusion server and then add the IP address of the machine where the CF Builder is installed to the `security.properties` file.

### Solution:

1. Setup the admin server instance. [Follow these guidelines](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusionBuilder/Using/WS0ef8c004658c1089-38317734121cdfd5fd3-7ffd.html)
2. Update the security property of the remote ColdFusion server

Open the `{CFHome}/runtime/lib/security.properties` file and update the values of `jrun.subnet.restriction` and `jrun.trusted.hosts` with the IP address of computer where ColdFusion Builder is installed. Alternatively, you can use the asterisk wildcard (*) as the IP address value, to allow the server to start and stop without any restriction.

### References:

[Setting up a remote server with ColdFuison Builder 3](http://blogs.coldfusion.com/post.cfm/setting-up-coldfusion-builder-3-with-a-remote-server)

[CF Docs - Add a remote server](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusionBuilder/Using/WS0ef8c004658c1089-38317734121cdfd5fd3-7ffd.html)

[CF Builder Docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusionBuilder/Using/cfbuilder_help.pdf)

### Note:

Download the `AdminServerComponents.zip` from [here](https://www.adobe.com/support/coldfusion/downloads.html#cfbuilderdevtools) under the ColdFusion Builder 3 Development Tools.

Comment: were you able to setup the CFBuilder for the remote server?